# VBA creating menu item to open file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created my own menu which lists files. I want to be able to click on a file name and workboo.open be called. How can I modify:

```
Set cbButton = vParentMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
cbButton.Caption = strSubMenuCaption
If strButtonOnAction <> "" Then cbButton.OnAction =
```

to achieve this? I understand I need to add some sort of action string which calls workbook.open with a reference to the file path (which I do have).

Comment: Where does this menu appear..? Within MS Excel..?

Comment: Its my code which is called upon Excel loading up. It adds a menu to the "Add in" ribbon. I have my menu showing all my files, I just want to open the file when I click on the button.

Comment: Cool. I am new to VB Scripting and want to create an add in menu item just like that.. Any pointers..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want something like:

```
cbButton.OnAction = "'<FunctionName> <Parametervalue>'"
```

If you are using a string parameter for the function you'd want to enclose the value in double quotes:

```
cbButton.OnAction = "'<FunctionName> """<Parametervalue>"""'"
```

eg:

```
cbButton.OnAction = "'OpenWB """c:\test.xls"""'"
```

Comment: I created a function which accepted a file Path as a parameter and just called Workbook.open Path. Then I did cbButton.OnAction = "foo " & path but it didn't work. Should it have been "foo '" & path & "'"?

Comment: Yes if the function param is a string you need double quotes surrounding it. If it still doesn't work post the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this..

```
Set cbButton = vParentMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
cbButton.Caption = strSubMenuCaption
If strButtonOnAction <> "" Then 
    With cbButton
        .OnAction = "'OpenWorkbook " & strButtonOnAction & "'"
    End With
End If

Sub OpenWorkbook(strFilePath)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
End Sub
```

Note that I haven't tested this myself...